# Existing MediaWiki content in plone site

Tags: mediawiki, plone-4.x

I have an existing MediaWiki site that I want to port into Plone. In the interim, is there a way to have Plone read from the wiki articles and present them within the context of my Plone site? I'd like to have a Plone page reference the URLs of MediaWiki articles and display them as if they were part of the Plone site.

Comment: On Wordpress there's a plugin called wiki-embed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [parse API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parse) to get the HTML from your wiki and embed said HTML in your other CMS, either dynamically server side, or with a frame (not so ideal), or with a script import update (depends on frequency of updates on your wiki).